# Is there something wrong with my query? Am I using Inner Join wrongly?

Tags: java, sql

I could use some assistance with my exam project, I have a problem with my SQL query for getting a list of volunteers(id) based on the guild(s)(id) they're in, it is a many to many relationship and have decided to use 'Inner Join' to tell my java program what id's are = to each other, but when I run it, it gives me the error 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.' Which supposedely means that the list I am trying to show is empty? Any immediate thoughts?

This is the many to many relationship between the 3 tables in diagram:

[image: This is the many to many relationship between the 3 tables in diagram]

The query to get the volunteer based on guild, first time using the Inner Join statement, so there might be an error here I have overlooked,
[image: The query to get the volunteer based on guild, first time using the Inner Join statement, so there might be an error here I have overlooked]

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Also the code, errors, expected results, sample data etc should be included in the question itself, not as links which may disappear and make the question useless to others.

Comment: It was recommended, but I see, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thank you Sami, my second question :-) I will up my game

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: `where guild.guildname = '?'` is wrong (unlesse you are looking for a name `?`) the JDBC placeholders must not be put between single quotes. So it should be: `where guild.guildname = ?`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need some more spaces at the beginning/end of your strings that you are concatenating.

You also need to select columns using a comma between them, not `and`.

e.g. `select firstname, lastname` ... instead of `select firstname and lastname ...`

Comment: Don't really know what concatenating means, but thanks for the tip on the comma, didn't change the output though

Comment: @JesperEnemark Where you are _adding_ strings together with "...." + "..."

Comment: @JesperEnemark for exemple `SELECT 'SQL ' + 'Server'` , that's a concatenation.

Comment: " *spaces*SELECT FirstName, LastName*spaces*" like this?

Comment: @JesperEnemark sure, but for each of the lines you are concatenating because `select ... from volunteerinner ...` is going to fail because you are missing a space between `volunteer` and `inner`.

Comment: Even though it is seperated by +?, not sure I fully get it, it seems like it is seperated.

Comment: Thank you anyway SqlZim and Sami, I will try to take a closer look with my DB teacher tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 0):

The '?' in the WHERE statement is considered a String in SQL, and since there were no GuildName with the string '*questionmark*' it tried to find a string in the GuildName column where there was non which resulted in an empty list. Also the concatenation of the strings were incorrect since there was no spacing between Volunteer and Inner. Fixed it. Thanks for the replies.